# How can I regain administrative privileges after a virus infection?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, virus, administrator, virus-removal

Is there software that allows you to bypass administrator restrictions? The problem is a virus has restricted me from doing anything; I can't install anything because I don't have the administrator permission.  Is there software you can recommend to overcome this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of user accounts and privileges is that you *can't* just bypass them and do what you want.  Once Windows has booted, barring any security holes in software running as a privileged account, you can't just "bypass" security.

However, depending on what the virus has done, you may be able to use the [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)  to enable and reset the password on the Administrator account, then use that account to log in and hopefully remove the virus.

If the virus somehow still locks you out while using the Administrator account, then you can try booting into safe mode (press F8 during startup) to see if that might help.  If not, you may need to format the hard drive to really eliminate the virus.  In fact, I recommend you plan on going that route anyway sometime soon since it's the best way to be sure the virus is completely gone.

Comment: tsk tsk I can't boot to my Safe Mode. I know this would be irrelevant to my previous question. But do you know other options how to boot to safe mode? In my friend's laptop I used to see a program inside his control panel that lets him boot in safe mode. Currently, I don't have a communication to my friend.

any advice?

Comment: Press F8 about once per second while the computer boots up (right before the black background Windows logo starts to appear). You'll get a menu that lets you boot to safe mode.